# Android - Tab Layout with Swipeable Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs

So I following the tutorial here [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

But, originally I got the error:

```
`Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11): android.app.ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled for the line actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);`
```

So then I added `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` to my class, and `@TargetApi(14)` to my `onCreate()`

But my activity still crashes on the same line with the following error:

```
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.HomeScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at my.package.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:102)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-26 18:17:32.381: E/AndroidRuntime(19944):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Edit your post and include line `102` of `HomeScreen.onCreate`, please. That's where you're throwing a `NullPointerException` according to your logcat.

Comment: `actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

line `102` is `actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);`

Comment: hi did any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Make minimum api version to 14 in manifest like this: `android:minSdkVersion="14"` and see what happens. Maybe the emulator/device you are testing on has lower api.

Otherwise use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to support lower apis.

Comment: that didn't work.  I had added `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` and `@TargetApi(14)` before too, and those didn't work as well.  I'm just testing it on my nexus 5 so not sure why that didn't work.  i'll try actionbarsherlock but i preferred to try this thing.   thanks